# Deleting products associated with user when deleting user

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Pretty new to Symfony - I am able to successfully delete a user, but I am having difficulty deleting all products associated with the user. My objective is to click a button in the admin backend and delete the user along with all products associated with the user.

I have tried several approaches and got a little lost in my own pursuit. I reverted back to the original code that successfully allows me to delete the user.

Any feedback will be appreciated. Not sure if I need to include VendorRepository as well.

**UserRepository.php**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    // get access to the entity manager
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    // get the user from the repository by id
    $user = $em->getReference('Thinkfasttoys\Core\Entity\user', $id);
    // use built in methods to delete the user
    $em->remove($user);
    // update the database with the change
    $em->flush();
}
```

**ProductRepository.php**

```
public function deleteAllProductsByVendorId($vendorId)
{
    // @Todo: revisit this at a later date and determine if the vendor id is actually required
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete("Thinkfasttoys\Mapwatch\Entity\Product","p")
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.vendor', ':vendor'))
        ->setParameter(':vendor', $vendorId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}

public function delete($id)
{
    // @Todo: switch to vendor id, instead of user id
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete("Thinkfasttoys\Mapwatch\Entity\Product","p")
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.vendor', ':vendor'))
        ->setParameter(':vendor', $vendorId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Service - Users.php**

```
    public function delete($id)
{
    $this->repository->delete($id);
}
```

**Controller - AdminController**

```
    /**
 * @Route("/admin/user/delete/{id}", name="admin_user_delete")
 * @Template
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $this->get('users')->delete($id);

    // create the user event and dispatch it
    $event = new UserEvent($id);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(UserEvents::USER_DELETED, $event);

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice-success', 'User deleted successfully.');

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_user_list'));
}
```

**Entity - BaseUser.php**

```
class BaseUser
{
/**
 * Primary key and id of the record
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * Activation code used for the user
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $activationCode;

/**
 * This should limit the user to specific domain, but should be optional
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 */
protected $domain;

/**
 * The email of the user
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 *
 */
protected $enabled;

/**
 * The password of the user
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * The signup code of the user, if any
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $signupCode;

/**
 * Date and time when the user requested a password
 *
 * @var datetime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 *
 */
protected $passwordRequestedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * This is a temporary variable to reference the existing mongodb object,
 * once the migration is complete, this can be dropped
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $mongoUserId;

public function __construct($username = null, $password = null, array $roles = null)
{
    $this->email = $username;
    $this->password = $password;

    if ($roles == null) {
        $this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');
    } else {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    $this->enabled = false;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getActivationCode() {
    return $this->activationCode;
}

public function setActivationCode($activationCode) {
    $this->activationCode = $activationCode;

    return $this;
}

public function getDomain()
{
    return $this->domain;
}

public function setDomain($domain)
{
    $this->domain = $domain;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function setEnabled($enabled)
{
    $this->enabled = $enabled;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

public function getSignupCode() {
    return $this->signupCode;
}

public function setSignupCode($signupCode) {
    $this->signupCode = $signupCode;

    return $this;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    $salt = strrev(str_replace('@', '_', $this->email));
    return $salt;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getSalt() !== $user->getSalt()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getUsername() !== $user->getUsername()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


public function getPasswordRequestedAt() {
    return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
}

public function setPasswordRequestedAt($passwordRequestedAt = null) {
    $this->passwordRequestedAt = $passwordRequestedAt;

    return $this;
}

public function isPasswordRequestNonExpired($ttl)
{
    return $this->getPasswordRequestedAt() instanceof \DateTime &&
    $this->getPasswordRequestedAt()->getTimestamp() + $ttl > time();
}

public function getPasswordResetCode()
{
    $current = '';

    if ($this->getPasswordRequestedAt() != null) {
        $current = $this->getPasswordRequestedAt()->getTimestamp();
    }
    return md5($current . ' ' . $this->getEmail());
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getMongoUserId()
{
    return $this->mongoUserId;
}

/**
 * @param string $mongoUserId
 */
public function setMongoUserId($mongoUserId)
{
    $this->mongoUserId = $mongoUserId;
}
```

}

**Entity - User.php**

```
class Users
{
protected $repository;
protected $metadata;
protected $userClass;
protected $superUserClass = 'Thinkfasttoys\Core\Entity\SuperUser';
protected $encoder;
protected $mailer;
protected $container;
protected $from_email;

protected $em;

public function __construct($em, $userClass, $mailer, $container)
{
    $this->userClass = $userClass;

    $this->em = $em;
    $this->metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($userClass);

    if (false !== strpos($this->userClass, ':')) {
        $this->userClass = $this->metadata->name;
    }

    $this->repository = $this->em->getRepository($userClass);

    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->container = $container;

    $this->from_email = $this->container->getParameter('default_from_address');

}

public function getUser($email)
{
    return $this->repository->findOneByEmail($email);
}

public function getUserById($id)
{
    return $this->repository->find($id);
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (get_class($user) !== $this->userClass) {
        $this->userClass = get_class($user);
        $this->repository = $this->em->getRepository($this->userClass);
    }
    $id = $this->metadata->getIdentifierValues($user);
    $user = $this->getUserById($id);
    return $user;
}

public function getAllUsers() {
    // make sure you only get non super admins
    return $this->repository->getAllUsers();
}

public function getAllUsersInArray($userIds) {
    // make sure you only get non super admins
    return $this->repository->getAllUsersInArray($userIds);
}

public function getAllExistingUserIds() {
    // make sure you only get non super admins
    return $this->repository->getAllExistingUserIds();

    //$existingUserIds = array();
    //
    //foreach ($results as $user) {
    //    $existingUserIds[] = $user->getId();
    //}
    //
    //return $existingUserIds;
}

public function getAllUsersByRole($roles) {
    // make sure you only get non super admins
    return $this->repository->getAllUsersByRole($roles);
}

public function getAllUsersByRoleAsArray($roles) {
    // make sure you only get non super admins
    return $this->repository->getAllUsersByRoleAsArray($roles);
}

public function getUserClass()
{
    return $this->userClass;
}

public function createUser($email, $rawpassword, $roles = array(), $activationCode = null, $signupCode = null, $enabled = false, $domain = null)
{
    $class = $this->userClass;
    $user = new $class($email, null, array());

    $password = $this->createHashPassword($rawpassword, $user->getSalt());

    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setPassword($password);
    $user->setRoles($roles);
    $user->setActivationCode($activationCode);
    $user->setSignupCode($signupCode);
    $user->setEnabled($enabled);
    $user->setDomain($domain);

    $this->repository->save($user);

    return $user;

}

public function updateUser($id, $email, $rawPassword, $roles = array(), $activationCode = null, $signupCode = null, $enabled = false)
{
    $user = $this->getUserById($id);

    $password = $this->createHashPassword($rawPassword, $user->getSalt());

    if (!empty($rawPassword)) {
        $user->setPassword($password);
    }

    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setRoles($roles);
    $user->setActivationCode($activationCode);
    $user->setSignupCode($signupCode);
    $user->setEnabled($enabled);

    $this->repository->save($user);

    return $user;

}

public function updateUserPassword($id, $rawPassword)
{
    $user = $this->getUserById($id);

    $password = $this->createHashPassword($rawPassword, $user->getSalt());

    if (empty($rawPassword)) {
        throw new \Exception("Password Is Blank!");
    }

    $user->setPassword($password);
    $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(null);

    $this->repository->save($user);

    $this->sendPasswordChangedEmail($user);

    return $user;

}

public function enableUser($id, $enabled = true) {
    $user = $this->getUserById($id);
    $user->setEnabled($enabled);

    $this->repository->save($user);

    return $user;
}

private function createHashPassword($rawpassword, $salt)
{
    $encoder = $this->getEncoder();
    return $encoder->encodePassword($rawpassword, $salt);
}

private function getEncoder()
{
    if ($this->encoder === null) {
        $this->encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder();
    }
    return $this->encoder;
}

public function delete($id, $vendorId)
{
    $this->repository->delete($id);
}

public function sendActivationEmail($email, $activationCode)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('User Registration Confirmation')
        ->setFrom($this->from_email)
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('CoreUsersBundle:Default:activationEmail.txt.twig', array('email' => $email, 'code' => $activationCode)));

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}

public function sendPasswordResetEmail($user)
{
    $current = new \DateTime('Now');
    $user->setPasswordRequestedAt($current);

    $this->repository->save($user);

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('You have requested a password reset')
        ->setFrom($this->from_email)
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('CoreUsersBundle:PasswordReset:recoveryEmail.txt.twig', array('hashString' => $user->getPasswordResetCode(), 'email' => $user->getEmail()) ), "text/html");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}

public function sendPasswordChangedEmail($user)
{
    // $hashString = md5($current->getTimestamp() . ' ' . $user->getEmail());

    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Your password has been changed' )
        ->setFrom($this->from_email)
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('CoreUsersBundle:PasswordReset:passwordChanged.txt.twig', array('hashString' => $user->getPasswordResetCode(), 'email' => $user->getEmail()) ), "text/html");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

}

**View - twig - list.html.twig**

```
                    <tbody>
                {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{{ path('admin_user_edit', {'id': user.id}) }}">{{ user.email }}</a></td>
                        <!-- <td>{#{ user.domain }#}</td> -->
                        <td>
                            {# @ToDo: There has to be a better way to do this #}
                            {% for role in user.roles %}
                                {% if role == 'ROLE_ADMIN' %}Administrator{% endif %}
                                {% if role == 'ROLE_USER' %}User{% endif %}
                                {% if role == 'ROLE_VENDOR' %}Vendor{% endif %}
                                {% if role == 'ROLE_RENTAL' %}Rentals{% endif %}
                                {% if role|length > 1 and not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ user.isEnabled ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="{{ path('admin_user_edit', {id: user.id }) }}"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white pull"></i> Edit</a>
                            <a {% if not user.isEnabled %}data-toggle="modal" data-url="{{ path('admin_user_resend_activation', {'id': user.id}) }}" href="#modal-send-confirmation"{% endif %} class="{% if user.isEnabled %}disabled{% endif %} send btn btn-small btn-success"><i
                            class="icon-envelope icon-white"></i> Resend Activation Email</a>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-url="{{ path('admin_user_delete', {'id': user.id}) }}" href="#modal-delete-confirmation" class="delete btn btn-small btn-danger"><i
                                    class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Are these products 'associated' with the user's entity? As in through a join on the user entity? Does your database enforce any FK constraints?

Comment: FK constraints are dropped - I have attached the user entity

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I am not seeing a relationship between the user entity and these products.

You could set up a one-to-many for user-to-product (xref/join table/whatever you call it) and let Doctrine handle it for you.

```
/**
  * @var Collection
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserProductsXref",mappedBy="user", cascade=
{"persist","remove"})
  */
 private $products;
}
```

Or, proceed with what seemed to be your intent. Fire off some repository method and programmatically remove the associated rows. What exactly didn't work with your approach using `deleteAllProductsByVendorId()`?